# Set the vertical scroll bar to a particular position when autoscroll is true

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a data grid where i have a row with blue color. I want to place the position of the vertical scroll bar in such a way that the blue colored row is visible. My auto scroll property is set to true. So whenever i try setting some value to it the vertical scroll bar disappears.

Comment: You describe *what* you are trying to achieve (good) and some specifics of how you try (not bad), but: what *is* your specific question? (I like that spelt out in the post, so I don't have to guess combining problem description and title.) Do you have more rows than the window can display?

Comment: Yes... i have more rows than windows can display..

Answer (score 0):

You can set the position of the vertical scroll bar using this property.

```
// Search for the row index you want to display using LINQ
var someRowIndex = dgNew.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Cells["SomeColumnName"].Value != null &&
                         a.Cells["SomeColumnName"].Value.ToString() == "Value of some column in the blue row")?.Index;

if (someRowIndex != null)
{
    dg.FirstDisplayedCell = dg.Rows[someRowIndex].Cells[0];
}
```

Comment: what should be the row index?

Comment: You just use the index of the row you've highlighted blue.  I've edited my answer to show how to do that using a bit of LINQ.